# Run Java Program As Daemon Service Following Guide Not Working ?? (RHEL 5)

Tags: java, linux, daemon, rhel, rhel5

I am trying to run the program as mentioned here: http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/7.htm

while running the following command, I see error:

```
./javaDaemonTest.sh install
```

The error is as follows

```
./javaDaemonTest.sh: line 29: .: /etc/rc.status: is a directory
./javaDaemonTest.sh: line 193: rc_reset: command not found
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/sbin/rcjavaDaemonTest' to `/var/local/javaDaemonTest/javaDaemonTest.sh': File exists
./javaDaemonTest.sh: line 221: rc_exit: command not found
```

How to debug it? Or, if you are following this guide, are you getting this error? My `JAVA_HOME` path is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The line 29 is

```
  . /etc/rc.status
```

Which indicates it should have been a file.  The script may be specific to SUSE (SLES). What is your OS/distribution?   You are better off with trying the solution outlined in the same link..

Comment: what do you mean by OS i am using Red hat linux 5 and what you told about solution i have not understood ??

Comment: The web page you referred has mentioned only SLES as tested platform..   You need to check why /etc/rc.status a directory instead of file.