# How would I run my Java program as a daemon in RHEL 5

Tags: java, linux, jar, daemon

hi i want to run my java program as daemon service as i have a jar file for that program does any one has general daemon script that runs at boot and can be start stop and restart so please share it with me 
   in which i will simply change the path of jar with my jar file and i would use it

i have search for it a lot i have found 2 to 3 script but they have some error so i cant use them i will mention there link also,

```
http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/7.htm

http://www.apexninjas.com/blog/f?p=100:1:0::::P1_ARTICLE:1460

http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/?p=139
```

the last link is not giving any error but it is not running service too as i check it using command "service vsftpdg status" so there is no service found error in that last link i use code and just change the path for my jar file and it would be like this,

```
nohup java -jar /usr/local/vsftpdg/helloworld.jar /usr/local/vsftpdg 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
    echo $! > /usr/local/vsftpdg/pid
```

and the path changes the same as it need in the further code i mentioned the way i change the file path as above
 after a serarching for more then a week i am asking for general script that would run my jar file

Hopes for your help thanks in advance

Comment: Overlap? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998543/run-java-program-as-daemon-service-following-guide-not-working-rhel-5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Method to run a Java Application as a *nix Daemon or Windows Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530/best-method-to-run-a-java-application-as-a-nix-daemon-or-windows-service)

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson it is not duplicate there is some other link use in it and the problem is also some thing different

Comment: @ skaffman but there isn't any example script in that post

Comment: @SyedRaza That's why I didn't call it a duplicate, just an overlap. Thought the pointer may be useful.

Comment: @All i have successfully complete my task with the help of you people APEXNINJA link help me out you have configure it according to your need ... . :)